# Add new row when previous "new row" is saved in Kendo Grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have created a kendo.data.dataSource without transport (only data with model and fields) with success, and I am able to bind it to the KendoUI Grid on my page.

After loading, the grid is empty.  I do calling the net line to add a empty data item in the grid so the user can enter data directly in the grid (inline mode).

```
$("#divid").data("kendoGrid").addRow();
```

This all works.

But after the user finished the input and hit the OK/Save button, I like to add a new empty row immediatly, below the previous added row. I try this during the grid function Save:

```
save: function(e) {            
    $("#divid").data("kendoGrid").addRow();
}
```

But the previous row with inserted data disappear and a new empty dataitem isn't added.

Also trying this same way during the datasource event 'change', but with the same behaviour.

My question is, what I doing wrong or what is the best way to add a new empty row to the Kendo Grid when user hits the OK/save button of a current inine editing row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save multiple record at a time, you can go for batch editing. You can bind a keypress event to create new row as well. Try this:

```
 $(document.body).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
}
});
```

13 is the value for enter key.